# How to validate a text box entry against a radio button list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Most query examples I find is the other way around, but I am looking to validate a text box entry (string?) against a radio button list and then display that string as a text field.
Anyone out there know how to do this?

```
if (textBox1.TextIndex > -1)
{
image.umageUrl = "/Images/" + RadioButtonList1.TextIndex.Text + ".jpg"
}
```

So, to try and explain a bit better.

I had a RadioButton list with a couple of options. Every option displays an image.
But I want to also put in a text box. If someone enters the same word as one of the RadioButton list, then it will also display the image. There is also a submit button

Hope I made this a bit clearer.

I also found this online:

```
For I = 0 To listOfStrings.Count - 1
            If myString.Contains(lstOfStrings.Item(I)) Then
                Return True
            End If
        Next
        Return False
```

but this doesn't exactly work for me either.

UPDATE

---

I figured it out. Can now do what I wanted it to do. I added the ELSE part. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ColourChoice
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AssignImageURL();
        }

        protected void Image1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AssignImageURL();
        }

        private void AssignImageURL()
        {
            if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text + ".png";
            }
            else 
            {
                Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + TextBox1.Text + ".png";
                Label1.Text = "You typed the colour " + TextBox1.Text;
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AssignImageURL();
        }

        protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AssignImageURL();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some code to show us what you have tried?

Comment: What are you trying exactly

Comment: Please add the code to the question, not in the comments.

Comment: Added some better explanation to the question.

Comment: What's the `TextIndex` property?

Comment: In the radiobuttonlist I used RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndexChanged - so TextIndex is where my problem lies, I guess. I am new at all of this, sorry.

Comment: It's still not clear what you want to achieve. Basically you leave room to a lot of guessing. Please consider revising your question's content or it you will not get (m)any answers for it.

Comment: I am not sure how I can explain this any better, but I will try later today.

Comment: Hi Alex.
Figured it out. I just added the else statement.
See code above.
Regards

Comment: @user2110655: feel free to answer your own question! That's not a crime in here ;)

Answer (score 0):

On submit button, you can check whether Textbox1.text is equal to contents of Radiobutton list.
Something like this

```
if (TextBox1.Text != "")
        {
            int b=0;
            while (b < RadioButtonList1.Items.Count)
            {
                if (TextBox1.Text == RadioButtonList1.Items[b].Text)
                {
                     Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + Textbox1.Text + ".png";
                    break;
                }
                b++;
            }
        }
```